# Connection string throws a SqlConnection Error

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, visual-studio-2017

my connection string:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANUPAM-DESKTOP\ANUPAM;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
```

But it is showing this error:

[image]

What can I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash character (`\`) is used as an escape character, so it thinks your string includes `\A`, which is apparently not a valid escape character. To force the backslash character to be recognized correctly, escape *it* by doubling it:

`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANUPAM-DESKTOP\\ANUPAM;` ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding '@' before the string:

I added '@' Sign before the Connection String and then it works.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ANUPAM-DESKTOP\ANUPAM;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
```